# Create a bootable USB with DFT using UNetbootin

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, unetbootin

My Dell inspiron 8600 crashed and on restarting its showing the "unmountable boot volume" error. Occasionally the HDD is also making a strange clicking noise. I suppose the HDD has died. It looks like the best way to know is to run Hitachi DFT.

However, it does not have a CD drive or a floppy drive. I am trying to get the DFT iso (dft32_v416_b00) loaded using UNetbootin to a flash drive by selecting the DFT iso as a disk image in UNetbootin. However, when I use the flash drive to boot, it boots into UNetbootin ok but how do I run DFT. I have never ran DFT before, so not getting it. Not sure if this is the right way to do it.

This post is similar but does not answer how to do it with UNetbootin
http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=9318

Do I have to use UBCD for this?

Comment: I want to know, how to get past the default blue UNetbootin boot menu and start DFT

Answer (score 1):

The "Automatic boot in 10 seconds..." countdown loop is a UNetbootin problem. If the UNetbootin boot menu does not have an entry for the OS you are trying to boot to under the **Default** boot menu entry, this is another sign that UNetbootin is not working properly. I know that it's a problem with UNetbootin because I have seen it before, and managed to solve it by reformatting the USB flash drive to remove to bootloader and then making the live USB again with [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).

Comment: I can see "default". But when I click on it the same screen shows up with the timer reset to 10 sec. Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: So what is the right way and the right version? Should I try UBCD instead?

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way out. Instead of using UNetbootin I used UBCD. The only flip side is the iso file size which is over 500 mb. However, moving it to the flash drive and using it is extremely easy. Also, other than DFT it has a huge set of other useful hardware tools.